How to define function argument as an other function argument
For example how to impalement Wrapper::call_to_func
that argument list call_to_func should be as func
class A
{
    void func(int, char, double);
};

template<class T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    void call_to_func(....)
    {
          m_t.func(....)
    }

    T m_t;
}


Pretty much the same as https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

To store a function use std::function. Works very well with lambdas.

You can make call_to_func a variadic method template with a template parameter pack , and use std::forward to perfectly forward the arguments to func:
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class A {
public:
    void func(int i, char c, double d) {
        std::cout << "func" << " " << i << " " << c << " " << d << "\n";
    }
};

template<class T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    template <typename ... Ts>
    void call_to_func(Ts&& ... args) {
        m_t.func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

    T m_t;
};

int main() { 
    Wrapper<A> w;
    w.call_to_func(1, 'a', 2.3);
}

Output:
func 1 a 2.3

Live demo

As commented below, if you want to support non-void methods as well, you can change call_to_func to be:
template <typename ... Ts>
decltype(auto) call_to_func(Ts&& ... args) {
    return m_t.func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}

Note the usage of decltype(auto) for return type forwarding.
Live demo 2

And even auto call_to_func(Ts&& ... args) -> decltype(m_t.func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)) to be SFINAE friendly, and allow to return same type (add then missing return). noexcept(noexcept(m_t.func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)))) might even be added.

@Jarod42 adding the return type with decltype will require to move the declaration of T m_t above call_to_func, isn't it ?

Yes, or use std::declval<T>().

FWIW, auto call_to_func(Ts ... args) { return m_t.func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...); } also works with void: https://godbolt.org/z/s187oM3Gh

@NathanOliver yes, my "Live demo 2" above incidentally shows exactly this case. This is also why I wrote "support non-void methods as well".

What I was getting at was -> decltype(std::declval<T>().func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)) is not needed.  The auto return type will see that return m_t.func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...); is void and it will deduce as void.  Really since this is a wrapper decltype(auto) might be more appropriate since if the function returns a reference type then decltyp(auto) will pick that up.  Just auto will drop the reference qualification.

@NathanOliver now I see what you mean. Yes it is more elegant indeed. Just to make sure: so with decltype(auto) it should it be like this ?

@wohlstad Yep, no trailing return type required.

@NathanOliver that's an elegant finishing touch, updated.

@wohlstad Can you please to explain what differ between your code and call_to_funcA(Ts ... args) {  mt_func (args...).

@herzlshemuelian my code uses what is called "perfect forwarding". It doesn't matter so much for primitive types like int. But it matters for other types which might be important in generic code. See more info about it here (there is also a link in my answer): What are the main purposes of std::forward and which problems does it solve?. googling "c++ perfect forwarding" will give you even more info if you want to get deaper into the subject.
